# How to allow pauses in twilio studio gather input

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-studio

I am working on an IVR in Twilio studio in which the caller needs to read out their id number in order to check their point balance. Everything works well except if the caller pauses between numbers the Gather input widget thinks they are done with the number and proceeds to the next widget making an incorrect HTTP GET request. Is there a way to do this differently where the IVR will wait at least 5 seconds in between pausing before processing the speech input?

Comment: A way would be to ask the user for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Gather input widget has a setting "Stop Gathering After" which allows you to choose a number of seconds that it will let the user pause before continuing. The default should be 5 seconds, but you may want to test with it to see the effect and work out what's best for your users.

[image: The Stop Gathering After option comes after Number of Loops]

Comment: The issue however is when the caller begins to speak then pauses between numbers. I put the "stop gathering after" up to 20 seconds but it doesnt change the result. I thought about creating a function with twiml and using the timeout method but it seems as if that might not work either.

Comment: The good news is that we are aware of this and we have an internal ticket to add `speechTimeout` support. If you want to follow it, I recommend you raise a ticket with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to ask to be notified when support has been added.

Comment: speechTimeout only works before user starts talking.  If they pause in the middle of a sentence the gather will complete and move on.  The only way to handle it seems to be with websockets which requires a massive amount of work compared to using gather.

Answer (score 0):

Studio uses the Auto speech model, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout. It doesn't currently offer the option based of a speechTimeout. Hopefully, this feature will be available soon.